# MongoDB complex query

Tags: mongodb, doctrine, database

I am writing a data cleanup task for a very large Collection with more than 80,000,000 objects.

Each object has:
- an item ID: item_id
- start date: log_date
- end date: log_to (Optional)

Basically:

```
if log_to is defined
    then
        if log_to > 6 months ago
        then
            remove object
        endif
else log_from > 6 months ago
then
    remove object
endif
```

This is pretty easy, however my problem is with the next requirement, which is to keep the most recent object (record of the item), even if the date is before 6 months ago.

I want to do this using only one query... any idea?

And I am also using Doctrine, but if this is not possible using Doctrine.

Comment: Is your question: for each item_id `my_item_id`, I want to keep only one document with `item_id: my_item_id` and this should be the most recent of all the documents with `item_id: my_item_id`? Would you do it in the mongo shell, if not with Doctrine?

Comment: mmhh not really. I want to keep one record (the latest) if there is no record within the last 6 months for an item_id (therefore that record will be before 6 months ago) or keep all records within these 6 months and removing all records before 6 months ago

Comment: I do not think this is possible using only one query, because you need to browse the entire collection at least twice, in order to establish the "most recent" record you need in the second case. If you browse the collection for the first time and you get a given doc `A` for the first time, you are not able to say if you have to keep it or not because maybe you will have other documents thereafter with the same `item_id`. You can still use *only one* `remove` query  with a `$where` condition, but you will necessarily have another query into it: very bad performance.